# how to create a full-width dropdown menu using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to create my custom full width menu using a simple hover function but my problem is as soon the mouse move out of the menu the subdiv also hides.
Can you help me with my code?

Here's my nav

## HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown" id="open-block-menu">
        <a href="about-flax" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ONLINE STORE </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="top-block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

## JS

```
$('#open-block-menu').hover(function() {
        $('.top-block').slideDown();
    }, function() {
        $('.top-block').slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `hover` method, you could use `mouseenter and mouseleave` as below, so every-time when `mouseenters` it show below `menus` and on `mouse pointer leave` below menu hides again.

```js
$('#open-block-menu').on("mouseenter",function() {
  $('.top-block').slideDown();
}); 
$('.top-block').on("mouseleave",function() {
  $(this).slideUp();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown" id="open-block-menu">
        <a href="about-flax" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ONLINE STORE </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="top-block">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I didn't think about using that function :)

Comment: Welcome @Jerielle :-) Glad that worked. Using hover too it helps but not here when working with menus.

Comment: Thanks again for the idea because I am trying to replicate the yamm3 plugin because it is not compatible on my layout. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change ur markup like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown" id="open-block-menu">
        <a href="about-flax" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ONLINE STORE </a>
        <div class="top-block">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```